# Disqus comment count HTTPS

Tags: meteor, https, disqus

Since i've upgrade my site on HTTPS, i can't get comment count. My website work with MeteorJS and i use [this module](https://github.com/webtempest/meteor-disqus/blob/master/disqus.coffee) :

```
  loadCounts: ->
    unless @shortName
      console.log 'Disqus needs a shortname. eg disqus = new Disqus(shortname)'
      return

    window.disqus_shortname = @shortName
    window.DISQUSWIDGETS = undefined
$.getScript("http://" + @shortName + ".disqus.com/count.js")
```

Do you know if i need to change my configuration on disqus for enable https ? Maybe Nginx configuration too ?

Answer (score 1):

If your page is in https all the other resources should be secure including Disqus. So try one of the two following changes

```
$.getScript("//" + @shortName + ".disqus.com/count.js")
```

or this

```
$.getScript("https://" + @shortName + ".disqus.com/count.js")
```

Comment: Hi Hannoun, i've test and no result :( : stephane-richin.fr

Comment: Before change HTTPS on getScript, yep, warning about non HTTPS, but now, no network errors on my console. You can see on https://stephane-richin.fr